# Using ElementTree to parse XML - python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have a an XML file that I have parse out the data with ElementTree.  However, I want to parse the data and set it equal to a variable so then I can output it to .csv file.

Here is a snipet of the XML file:

```
<Item ID="productID" TableID="itemvp">
<ItemField TableFieldID="name" Value="totally awesome product"/>
<ItemField TableFieldID="code" Value="product code"/>
<ItemField TableFieldID="dimensions" Value="34&quot;W x 65&quot;D x 39&quot;H"/>
<ItemField TableFieldID="caption" Value="description"/>
<ItemField TableFieldID="upc" Value="upc code"/>
<ItemField TableFieldID="sale-price" Value="2599.95"/>
</Item>
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root.iter('ItemField'):
    print child.attrib
```

This prints out the data in the following format:

```
{'TableFieldID': 'name', 'Value': 'totally awesome product'}
```

Which is basically a dictionary.  What I can't figure out is how to parse it so that I can set the value of "name" (totally awesome product) to a variable called "productName".  Any ideas on how to do this?  The end result is to export this data in .csv.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your loop, check if the `TableFieldID` is `name`, then set the `productName` variable to the `Value`:

```
for child in root.iter('ItemField'):
    if child.attrib['TableFieldID'] == 'name':
        productName = child.attrib['Value']
```

Comment: if I wanted to set several different values to variables would I have to run them all through an if statement? like so: 

    root = tree.getroot()
    for child in root.iter('ItemField'):
        if child.attrib['TableFieldID'] == 'code':
            productCode = child.attrib['Value']
        
        if child.attrib['TableFieldID'] == 'name':
            productName = child.attrib['Value']'

Comment: You can also use XPath syntax to locate a desired element: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support